# Control the seed of an object from another object

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

Suppose *object A* is instantiated in *object B* in geometry nodes. Can I control the seed value of *object A* from *object B*. Is there any way to transfer the seed value in this way?

[image]

Comment: Can you please illustrate a little more precisely what you mean? ...with a picture, perhaps?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/I8mOiwy

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in this way. An instance is a linked duplicate of a single object whose properties have been specified exactly once. If you change the seed value, all instances will change as well. Since there is no seed value at all for the model "Suzanne", I assume you want to do something completely different. Could you possibly share your file with us? There may be another solution to your question.

Comment: I have a similar problem with understanding as @quellenform here... I also assume you maybe want something completely different. I actually don't understand what you mean with "the seed value of _object A_". Suzanne is a mesh object that depicts a monkey head. There is no seed value there. A seed value is usually changing between different random distributions.  If you mean, you want to distribute Suzanne randomly on the mesh of _object B_ instead of regularly on the original vertices, you should first of all use a _Distribute Points on Faces_ before the _Instance on Points_.

Comment: You have understood correctly @quellenform. Now I understand that its not possible :) .

Comment: @SatyakiMandal This does not mean that it is impossible to solve your issue. ;-) However, it depends on what exactly you want to do. Please tell us more.

Comment: Currently I make an object using geometry node. Then make few versions of them with seeds value. And then I use the collection with those objects in another geometry node. I want to eliminate the need to make the variations of them manually.